# Deploy Liberty packaged server automatic delivery

Tags: github, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, devops, delivery-pipeline

I am working in a Websphere Liberty application that, because of particular server.xml configurations, i am deploying via packaged servers to Bluemix.

I want to work the code in GitHub, and have it automatically deployed to Bluemix using Toolchain / Delivery Pipeline. Is it possible ?

Currently, i have to do manually the task of packaging the server and deploying it to Bluemix.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is totally possible and the toolchain with GitHub and Delivery Pipeline integrations can solve problems just like this. You can even have the toolchain build and publish the application to Bluemix automatically when you push to your GitHub repository.

You can view the [toolchain docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/toolchains/toolchains_about.html)

or you can create a [toolchain from a template](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/devops/create) to help you get started and play around with the Delivery Pipeline integration to build your packaged server.

I have an [example toolchain](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/09/microservices-store-sample-on-bluemix/) (Click **Create Toolchain** button at the bottom) that may be helpful for you to create and poke around with as it includes a toolchain with GitHub and delivery pipeline integrations to build a liberty app with a packaged server. It also pushes it to Bluemix (the orders application).